# Laravel Eloquent nested whereHas returns everything

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have this tables with relations:

```
-categories (has many products)
-products (has many features)
-features
```

im trying to get a special category using its slug, and get the products in category, and i also want to filter the products by some features using `(id)`

my code:

```
$category = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('features', function ($query2) {
        $query2->where('id', 21); // Example id (products where has features with '21' id)
    });
})->where('slug', 'category-slug')
  ->with('products:id,title', 'products.features')->get();
```

but the code returns that category with all products (with or without features with id 21)

what is the solution?

Comment: Is the code only not executing `$query2` condition when you're using variable or its also not running when you hardcoded it?

Comment: @MuhamadRafiPamungkas yes. in every mode its not working and it will return all products in category

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [dot notation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence):

```php
$category = Category::whereHas('products.features', function ($query) {
        $query->whereKey(21);
    })
    ->where('slug', 'category-slug')
    ->with('products:id,title', 'products.features')->get();
```

Comment: unfortunately its still returns all products with all features (with or without 21 id)

Comment: @K1-Aria dot notation should be working as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) states it should work. Do this, instead of running `->get()` replace it by `->toSql()` and share the results with us here please.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use a pivot table which stores product features.

```
+------------------+
| categories       |
| features         |
| feature_product  |
| products         |
+------------------+
```

*Notice that pivot table name should be in alphabetical order prior to Laravel convention.*

Columns of feature_product:

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| feature_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now add relation to your product Model:

```
public function features() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class);
}
```

The query:

```
$products = Product::select()
        ->join('feature_product', function ($join) {
            $join->on('feature_product.product_id', 'products.id')
                ->where('feature_id', 21);
        })
        ->join('categories', function ($join) {
            $join->on('products.category_id', 'categories.id')
                ->where('slug', 'slug-name');
        }) 
        ->get();
```

Now get features per product:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
         $product->features;
}
```